# Java: Клиент не коннектится к серверу по внешнему IP

Tags: сеть, tcp-ip, java

Друзья, подскажите в чем проблема!
Написал простейший эхо-сервер и клиент к нему, как во множестве примеров в интернете. Сервер слушает порт 45000. Клиент отлично устанавливает связь с 45000-м портом при указании в сокете ip 127.0.0.1, моего внутреннего IP 192.168.1.2, и даже IP включенного Hamachi =) Но стоит указать внешний IP(он абсолютно точно у меня есть) - и всё: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. Везде написано, что это значит, что этот порт не слушается никакой службой. Через telnet такая же ситуация.
Но вот незадача: когда я проверяю, открыт ли 45000-й порт, например, через http://2ip.ru/check-port/ , то этот сайт вполне нормально обращается к порту и показывает, что он открыт, а сервер пишет в консоль "Client connected", то есть по идее всё работает, но только не с моего компа. Никак не могу понять, в чем проблема и как ее решить.
Возможно, проблема как-то свзязана с тем, что у меня ADSL, но порт 45000 я пробросил, так что по идее всё ОК должно быть.

На всякий случай, код сервера и клиента:

**Сервер:**

```
public class Server {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Server side");
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter    out= null;

    ServerSocket servers = null;
    Socket       fromclient = null;

    // create server socket
    try {
      servers = new ServerSocket(45000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't listen to port 45000");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
      System.out.print("Waiting for a client...");
      fromclient= servers.accept();
      System.out.println("Client connected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Can't accept");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    in  = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(fromclient.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(fromclient.getOutputStream(),true);
    String         input,output;

    System.out.println("Wait for messages");
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
     if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
     out.println("S ::: "+input);
     System.out.println(input);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
    fromclient.close();
    servers.close();
  }
}
```

**Клиент:**

```
public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Welcome to Client side");

    Socket fromserver = null;
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");

    System.out.println("Connecting to... 127.0.0.1");

    fromserver = new Socket(ipAddress,45000);
    BufferedReader in  = new
     BufferedReader(new 
      InputStreamReader(fromserver.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter    out = new 
     PrintWriter(fromserver.getOutputStream(),true);
    BufferedReader inu = new 
     BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String fuser,fserver;

    while ((fuser = inu.readLine())!=null) {
      out.println(fuser);
      fserver = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(fserver);
      if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) break;
      if (fuser.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    inu.close();
    fromserver.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tuhlom, stacktrace дадите? Ну или хотя бы на каком моменте исключение выбрасывается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не сможете через DNAT подключиться к своему же серверу на внешний IP, будучи в этой же подсети за этим же сервером..

Comment: Спасибо! То есть в принципе должно нормально подключаться со всех компов, кроме того, на котором сервак запущен?

Comment: Кроме всех компов вашей подсети.

Попробуйте тестировать через проксю или socks - то есть через третий (внешний) сервер.