# Как опубликовать rest приложение в ubuntu с локального ПК в интернет?

Tags: http, сеть, port, devops

Текст курсивом не имеем прямого отношения к вопросу.

*Я немного нарушу рекомендации по заведению вопроса. Если эту часть вопроса кто-то удалит - ни в коем случае не обижусь, но мне кажется, что это важно.
Я опытный java программист, но далеко не DevOps. Года 2 мечтал выдать что-то вовне с локального ПК, но не хватало знаний. Есть два вопроса на этом ресурсе, которые мне здорово помогли: [Java: Клиент не коннектится к серверу по внешнему IP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196618/java-%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-ip), [Как опубликовать локальный сервер?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535109/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80). Т.е. удовлетворяющее решение я нашёл на этом сайте, пока писал вопрос. Минутка благодарности. Далее по сути.*

Сделано следующее:

- Подключил белый IP у провайдера.
- IP на сайте https://2ip.ru/whois/ совпадает с IP в роутере
- По инструкции https://lumpics.ru/how-to-open-port-in-linux/ открыл
  порт 8777 (хотя это вроде необязательно)
- Запустил приложение на порту 8777
- По адресу http://localhost:8777/swagger-ui.html всё работает
- На сайте https://2ip.ru/check-port/?port=8777 показывается, что порт 8777 открыт

Но вот при попытке зайти по IP-шнику http://178.49.X.X:8777/swagger-ui.html выдаёт ошибку:

Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта 178.49.Х.Х.
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Оказалось, что к самому себе ходить не стоит по белому айпишнику :)

Но недопонятность осталась. Я хочу уметь ходить на сервер и удалённо и с локального ПК.

Насколько я понимаю, если я запущу npm приложение(WEB UI часть приложения), которое будет дёргать мой rest сервис , с локальной подсети оно будет ходить без ошибок только через localhost или IP, выданный роутером в подсети. А если ходить "извне" - то нужен белый IP.

Я вижу два варианта решения:

- Запустить UI часть сервиса в двух экземплярах на разных портах.
- Локально ходить через анонимайзер, или как-то иначе через посредников.

Оба варианты приемлемы и меня устраивают. Но как-то оно всё костылями пахнет.
Подскажите, какие есть более стандартные решения?

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что на роутере вы пробросили порт из внешки во внутрь?

Comment: На роутере открыл порты 8000-8999. У меня всё работает. Проблема в том, что если я добавлю UI часть к сервису - я натолкнусь на проблему, что локально для работы нужен 1 IP бекенда, а "извне" другой. Да вся информация в вопросе есть.

Comment: Все, теперь понял суть вопроса. У вас не полосатый провайдер? Я не силен в сетевых вещах прям сильно, но у провайдера может быть такая особенность топологическая, что сами к себе по белому ни-ни...

Comment: В общем, типа, если вы сидите за NAT'ом, то придти к самому себе по белому адресу и постучаться в NAT за которым вы сидите - вы не сможете. Вроде "кольцеванием" называется.

Answer (score 0):

Есть простой ответ :)
Локально у себя в etc/hosts можно дописать что-то вроде:

178.49.Х.Х   localhost

Где 178.49.Х.Х - наш белый IP роутера - и всё работает и локально и извне.

UPD: Пообщался сегодня со специалистом в этой теме, он мне собственно и напомнил, что такое etc/hosts. Он ещё говорил, что есть разные варианты, прописать в роутере DNS/пробросить как-то по хитрому порты/завязать это на купленный домен/поработать со шлюзом провайдера и прочее. Если накидаете чуть подробней в ответах что-нибудь об этом - заплюсую :)